# Detect Whether Device Supported by jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

Is there a way to test whether a given device is specifically on the [jQuery Mobile Supported Platforms](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/about/platforms.html) list, ideally with the support grade (A, B, C)?

I'm aware of [user agent matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/best-way-to-detect-handheld-device-in-jquery) (along with it's flaws).  That's not what I'm after.  If there were something similar to [jQuery Support](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a1/experiments/api-viewer/docs/jQuery.support/index.html) in jQuery Mobile, indicating that the device is a targeted mobile platform and which features are supported, that would be ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following to find out if browser is gradeA :

```
$.mobile.gradeA()
```

returns `true` / `false`

Comment: Cool.  Will that *only* return true for mobile browsers, or would e.g. a desktop browser that meets the general Grade A criteria also return true?  Is there better documentation than http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/globalconfig.html?

Comment: Desktop browsers WILL also return true / false based on the criteria.
http://jsfiddle.net/Bxt9D/